# Provisioning Profile, Certificate is not listing in xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

When I click on Code Signing Identity or Provisioning Profile, It gives me popup that says to enter value.. 
[image]

Check above Image, How to solve this??? 
Is it bug in xcode 6.2?

Bellow is account which has provisioning profile...
[image]

I have tried following things..

2 time restared mac

3 time restared xcode

tried on xcode 6.2 and 5.1

**EDIT**

I have tried Following all things.

- Refreshing Account
- Removed Account from Preference, Restart Xcode, Add Account again
- Removed All Certificates, Provisioning profile from Keychain Access, Removed Account from xcode, Removed All Certificates from portal. Recreated Certificates and Provisioning profile, Downloaded it again
- Removed All Certificates, Provisioning profile from Keychain Access, Removed Account from xcode, Removed All Certificates from portal. Recreated Certificates and Provisioning profile, Downloaded it again

I have Team Member Developer Account..

If I am missing anything to add here let me know..

Answer (score 2):

Adding your Profile by typing "iPhone Developer" does not make sense.

Do the following steps:

- go to the Apple [Member Center](http://developer.apple.com) and **download** all **certificates** and **provisioning profiles**
- **save** them somewhere you can access theme like on desktop
- **double-click** all of them, certificates and profiles
- this will bring up Xcode and the Keychain
- **close** Keychain as you won't need it anymore
- in Xcode, go to **Build Settings** to verify the profiles were added correctly
- **set** the Developer Code Signing Identity to your profile

Everything should work now.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I haven't type "IPhone Developer" my self, It was already there. I have tried removing account in xcode, After that removed "IPhone Developer" text from code signing and provisioning profile. Than I added account again and again "IPhone Developer" has been set..

Answer (score 1):

You must open the provisioning profile with xCode to be able to see it in the menu. Also, be sure that your Developer certificate's are in your keychain. If nothing else, try revoking them in your portal and recreate them.

Comment: I have did that. But Still I am not able to selecting provisioning profile and all that..

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :-

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> click on your Apple ID -> Click View Details -> click on your projects Provisioning Profile -> click the refresh button bottom left.